# How to insert a link to a folder

Tags: confluence

I can insert links to specified documents within folders, I want to be able to insert a link that takes the user to the folder to open up any document within.

I've tried something to the effect of this, but get an error ///server/share/etc

///server/share/etc

It wont take the file address that I am inputting in the 'insert link' option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can link to a folder, it should be in this format:

file:///"Drive":%5C"folder"%5C"folder"%20"folder"%5C"folder"%20"folder"/

Items in "" are to be filled in. the %5C is to separate folder names, and the drive from the first folder. %20 is used in place of spaces between words of a folder. like New%20Folder.